# Azure SQL Database Failover But Use Same DNS Name

Tags: azure, sql, failover

I am researching ways to make a highly available web application in Azure using the PaaS `App Service` and DBaaS `SQL Database` offerings.

`Standard` databases include `Standard Geo-Replication` to automatically replicate a database to a [pre-paired Azure region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/). When I create a database and set up geo-replication, it requires me to create a new server along with a new database. This means each server has its own DNS name (e.g. `mySqlServer.database.windows.net` vs `mySqlServerFailover.database.windows.net`).

I'd like my `App Service` to use a single DNS name that automatically points to whichever database is available. Preferably, that DNS name would also be geo-replicated, ensuring that even if an entire data center goes down, my site would still be available without intervention. I'd prefer to not have to change settings in my `web.config` file when the database fails over.

Are there any options available? Or do I need to have someone at the ready to switch over a site during a failover?

Comment: Found a relevant MSDN Forum thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0607c1bc-9b01-4738-9853-6c194267ef99/transparent-failover-sql-azure-database?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: And another thread, this one recommending having a second App Service in another region pointed to the secondary, failover database: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25c52d37-7cde-4b15-8f7d-1bb6d3ab271d/what-failover-does-sql-azure-support-automatically?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the DNS name for your site, [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/traffic-manager/) is what you need to have Azure fail over to a second location automatically in the event of a data center failure. You can configure traffic manager to either load balance between the regions in an Active/Active configuration or to fail over in an Active/Passive configuration

With your database URL it gets a bit more tricky, as you can't have an internal load balance between regions. Your effectively looking at having a second app service in the second data center pointing to the DR DB and then use traffic manager to balance between the two web apps. In a failover traffic manager directs traffic to the DR location, and the application is configured to talk to the DR DB.